# triggering pipeline job with github changes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I want to configure a cicd pipeline in jenkins, with every change in github the job has to be triggered automatically. I configured freestyle job and iam able to trigger my freestyle job with every push in the Github. When iam trying the same with my pipeline job it is not getting triggered.below is the configuration of pipeline job
[image]

[image]

and my pipeline code is simple to test with below code.I ran it once and twice to take effect. after that also for any change in my github my pipeline is not getting triggered automatically.

```
node {
        stage('test') {
       echo "test"
         }}
```

Could anyone let me know why my pipeline job is not able to automatically trigger with github changes when my freestyle job is able to trigger? What am i missing in my pipeline job?

I also added the below configuration as suggested but still no luck. Inspite of all the configuration for automatic triggering what am i missing here.
[image]

Comment: Hi there, can you check your jenkins logs to see if webhook is received by jenkins ?

Answer (score 0):

You need change job type to pipeline.
Inside you repository put Jenkinsfile and adjust hook.